# PDO FetchAll Into PHP Mail

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, fetchall

So here is where I get the current information from the database...

```
$ci = $currentinfo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And here is where I get some info from the past week...

```
$pi = $pastinfo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now I need a `foreach` statement that puts all of the information into a PHP mail function. Something along the lines of this...

```
foreach ($ci as $civalue) {
foreach($pi as $pivalue)

$result1 = $ci["info1"]-$pi["info1"];
$result2 = etc...
        $body = $result1, etc...;
        $to = '$civalue["email"]';
        $subject = 'Weekly Recap';
        $headers = 'From: noreply@gmail.com';
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ci); $i++) {
    $result[] = $ci[$i]["info1"] - $pi[$i]["info1"];
}


$body = implode(', ', $result);
$to = '$civalue["email"]';
$subject = 'Weekly Recap';
$headers = 'From: noreply@gmail.com';
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Thank you soooo much!